# ng-options not populating select options drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have tried implementing the changes provided in several examples yet none seem to work. I do have an ng-model and I clearly define the property of the object I would to receive. However it still does not work.
Any help would be great.

HTML

```
<select chose ng-model="selected" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in ansExplanOpt">
     <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.selected = ansExplanOpt.data;
```

The object is populating (I checked) and the properties it has are Name and Id.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: ng-model should be the selected value, not the array of options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.  Just looks like a misuse of the `ng-model` value.  Your code should be something like

```
<select chose ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="type.Id as type.Name for type in ansExplanOpt">
</select>
```

And the `ng-model` will be what the user has selected.

Their documentation breaks it down well also:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. I have looked over the angular docs and realize now that ng-model watches the item by reference not value.

Comment: @RyeGuy Great!  Glad it helped!

Comment: However it still does not work! Look at my changes above. Where is my error?

Comment: @RyeGuy what about changing your `ng-option` line to `ng-options="type.Id as type.Name for type in ansExplanOpt">` answer has been updated with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

`ng-model` is the value that user selected.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.ansExplanOpt = [
    {text:'learn angular', id:1},
    {text:'build an angular app', id:2}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<select chose ng-model="select" ng-options="type as type.text for type in ansExplanOpt">
     <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
</select>
{{select.text}}
  <br>
    {{select}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define which element in the array you want to be preselected:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    label: 'blah',
    value: 'blah'
  }, {
    label: 'blah1',
    value: 'blah1'
  }, {
    label: 'blah2',
    value: 'blah2'
  }];
  $scope.sel = $scope.data[0];

}]);
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  {{sel}}
  <select ng-model="sel.value" ng-options="d.value as d.label for d in data">
  </select>
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/8qzLkt77/) for more details